# Vhdl code for reading hex and converting to std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

Converting hexadecimal to binary

Comment: I'm assuming you know how to read files in general in VHDL. If not, Google 'VHDL textio'. I nearly voted to close this question on the grounds that it is a so-called "plz send teh codez" question. However, it is a reasonable question to ask for someone who knows how to read files in VHDL, but doesn't know how to read a hex value from a line, because there are dedicated VHDL statements to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need this package:

```
use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
```

**in addition to** `textio`. Then you can read a hex value from a line (`L`) into a `std_logic_vector` variable (`SLV`) using:

```
hread(L, SLV);
```

Comment: Under the -2008 standard revision procedure HREAD is available in IEEE arithmetic packages representing numbers as binary as well as in package std_logic_1164 without resorting to the use of Synopsys package std_logic_textio. It's also defined in package std.textio for type bit_vector.